# How to execute code from dynamic generated button

Tags: button, user-interface, hta, printers

i try to make a gui (hta) which can install on a client, one or more printers from the printer server.

the problem is when i create the button "install", the function is executed on form load and not by clicking on the button.

i don't understand why. can you help me please?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
    <TITLE>printer installation</TITLE>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID = 'AppBase'>

        <script language="VBScript">



    Dim WshNetwork, objPrinter, intDrive, intNetLetter
    strComputer = "change_printer_server_name_or_ip" 

    strHTML =  "<TABLE BORDER='0'>"

    Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
    Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer") 
    For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters 

        strHTML = strHTML & "<TR><TD><input type='button' value='install printer' name='" & objPrinter.Name & "' onclick='" & installprinter(printname, printserver) &"'>" & objPrinter.Name & "</input></TD><TD>" & objPrinter.Location  & "</TD><TD>" & objPrinter.portname & "</TD></TR>"

    next
    strHTML = strHTML & "</TABLE>"

    DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML

    function installprinter(printname, printserver)
        Set WshNetwork = CreateObject ("WScript.Network")
        on error resume next
        PrinterPath = "\\" & printserver & "\" & printname
        WshNetwork.RemovePrinterConnection PrinterPath, true, true
        WshNetwork.AddwindowsPrinterConnection (PrinterPath)
        msgBox "L'imprimante a été installée avec succès"
    end function


    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

     <span id="DataArea"></span>



</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

The load order of your page is important.

When you attempt to assign DataArea, the DOM is not yet initialised, so DataArea does not exist.  Here is a simple example of how to invoke your code when the DOM is ready:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>printer installation</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID = 'AppBase'>
    <script language="VBScript">
    strHTML =  "<TABLE BORDER='0'>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td>Testing</td></tr>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "</TABLE>"

    Function OnLoad()
        DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
    End Function
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad">
     <span id="DataArea"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the `<body onload="OnLoad">` and the new `Function OnLoad()`.

**EDIT** - Updated to include a function invoked from the generated html:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>printer installation</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID = 'AppBase'>
    <script language="VBScript">
    strHTML =  "<TABLE BORDER='0'>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td><button onclick=""TestingFunction"">Testing</button></td></tr>"
    strHTML = strHTML & "</TABLE>"

    Function OnLoad()
        DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
    End Function

    Function TestingFunction()
        MsgBox("Hello")
    End Function
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad">
     <span id="DataArea"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i still have the same problem but i used the structure you gave me.

Comment: Try isolating the problem; if you make strHTML = "Hello" does that function?  Keep adding code until it breaks, then diagnose from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling your **installprinter** routine when generating your HTML. Instead you need to format the HTML to be a valid call at the time the button is clicked. You want your eventual HTML to look like this:

```
<TR><TD><input type='button' value='install printer' name='PrinterName'
    onclick='installprinter "PrinterName", "PCName"'>PrinterName</input></TD>
    <TD>PrinterLoc</TD>
    <TD>PortName</TD></TR>
```

Note that since you're calling a sub, you exclude the parentheses. It looks weird but that's the way VBScript works. So your code to generate a table row should go like this instead:

```
strHTML = strHTML & "<TR><TD><input type='button' value='install printer' name='" & _
    objPrinter.Name & "' onclick='installprinter """ & objPrinter.Name & """, """ & _
    strComputer & """'>" & objPrinter.Name & "</input></TD><TD>" & _
    objPrinter.Location  & "</TD><TD>" & objPrinter.portname & "</TD></TR>"
```